# How add Export/Import Universal Type Identifier Icon to Xcode 12 Project?

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode12

I'm using Xcode 12 and I'm trying to adding Universal Type Identifier icon for export and import process.

So I have tried below ways for creating the icon.

1. added .png file to shared folder.
2. created .icns file using .png file via online tool and added it to project.
3. create .icns file using terminal command `iconutil -c icns icns.iconset`

But when i click plus button of the first screenshot,

[image]

it suggests three files in dialog like second screenshot.

[image]

if i choose one of them, it will not come to GUI and changes are not applied to project.
Please, help me to resolve this issue , i really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug of Xcode 12, but we can edit Info.plist manually.
If your icon file name is `appicon.png` try to edit the plist like below.

```
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>appicon</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>appicon</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feeback, i tried that part using above way (info.plist file was modified manually) , but it is alson not work. i added my images as a appiconset to Assets.xcassets in project. appiconset files are generating from https://appicon.co/

Comment: Did you try using a normal image set instead of an App Icon set?

Comment: like @Frederik said, it works with normal image instead of  App Icon. Just drag the icon file into the xcode project, and check the 'add to target' option.